# Permutations of 4 integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, permutation

I have to write a code that takes an input of 4 integers between  1 and 9 from a Scanner object and combines them in any way to equal 24. Although my solution is not the most elegant I have managed to compile a number of if statements using variables, b, c, d and was hoping to store the numbers entered by the user in an array and swap the values of a, b, c, d to generate each possible combination of numbers

for example one paring might be
(a+b*c) - d = 24. I'd want to switch the values of a, b, c, d for all possible combinations and for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this. This is what I have

```
public static void daGame(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int[] baseArray = {a, b, c, d};
    int [] keyArray = baseArray.clone();

    if(a > 9 || b > 9 || c > 9 || d > 9 || a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0 || d == 0){
        System.out.println("You entered a number greater than 9 or you enterered 0:");
        main(null);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < baseArray.length; j++){
            if(i == 1){
            baseArray = keyArray.clone();
            int temp = baseArray[0];
            baseArray[0] = baseArray[3];
            baseArray[3] = temp;
            j = baseArray.length - 1;
            }
            else if (i == 2){
            baseArray = keyArray.clone();
            int temp = baseArray[1];
            baseArray[1] = baseArray[0];
            baseArray[0] = temp;
            temp = baseArray[2];
            baseArray[2] = baseArray[3];
            baseArray[3] = temp;
            j = baseArray.length - 1;
            }else{
            int temp = baseArray[j];
            baseArray[j] = baseArray[baseArray.length - (1+j)];
            baseArray[baseArray.length - (1+j)] = temp;
```

this misses a lot of possible combinations

Comment: So what's the question? You don't have any question marks in your post.

Comment: since you need all combinations, have you tried a backtracking method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Just use a `permutation` method on both the arithmetic operations and the numbers.

Once you have the inputs from the the users turn them into a string:

```
void perm(std::string str, std::vector<std::string> &vec){
   perm("", str, vec);
}

void perm(std::string prefix, std::string str, std::vector<std::string &vec){
   int n = str.length();
   if( n == 0 ) vec.push_back(str);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      perm(pre+ str[i], str.substr(0,i) + str.substr(i+1,n), vec);
   }
}
```

Now you have a permutation method lets say you have the string:`1234` from the input you can permutate that string to get `2134 3214 1243 ... etc`

You can also do the same thing with the arithmetic operations i.e `+-*/`

or you can combine the operation:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
perm("1234" + "*-/+", vec);
```

Now you have a vector with all permuations of the numbers and the operations.
You can now prune the list to only accept `number operation number operations`.
This can be done with a regex:

```
 `\d[*|+|-|/]\d[*|+|-|/]\d[*|+|-|/]\d[*|+|-|/]`
 Then disregard the last operation.
```

Now that you have all the permutations as `strings`. Create some logic to turn it back to `ints`

NOTE:
There is wasted space here but this method should work.